# Postfix vs. Apache James

Tags: java, postfix-mta, james

Is there a difference between the two? Do they perform the same tasks?

I'm a little confused as I'm not too familiar with email servers, but I'm trying my hand at building one primarily to send transactional email from `Java` and there is very little documentation on `Apache James`. At the moment I do have it running properly, but I'm running into issues getting `DKIM` working properly with it and the frustration has made me consider changing.

So...is `Postfix` a suitable `Apache James` replacement? Will I need anything other than `Postfix` to send email from `Java`?

Comment: I personally found this question quite valuable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last time I tried `Apache James` was about 5 years ago. That time, `Postfix` was much, much more mature and stable than `Apache James`. However, it seems that `James` was greatly improved since then.

For me, `DKIM` problem you have, it has nothing to do with the mail server. It's totally a client task to properly sign email before sending with `DK/DKIM`.
Answering your other question, you will need `JavaMail` in your classpath (actually `mail.jar`, `smtp.jar`, `activation.jar`) to send emails from `Java`.

Comment: So, is James and Postfix really the same thing? James seems to be a full fledged email server, it can send email, receive, manage users, inboxes etc. Does postfix do all that as well?

Comment: Yeah. Postfix is `lighter` then heavyweight java-centric `James`.